# Fedora Failed to get D-Bus connection

Tags: fedora, mysql, d-bus

I have a VPS with fedora 16 installed. I have setup mysql and it was working a couple of days ago.

Now suddenly when I try to start mysql I get the error:

```
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Failed to connect to socket /org/freedesktop/systemd1/private: Connection refused
```

I'm not sure when mysql stopped working as I haven't worked with it in a couple of days. The only software I installed recently was jenkins and redmine.

Comment: Fedora 16 uses [`systemd`](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) to manage services (which uses [D-Bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus)).  How did you try to start `mysql`?  What's the output of [`systemctl status name-of-mysql-service`](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/15/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-services-running.html)? (Find `name-of-mysql-service` via `systemctl list-units`)

Comment: @sr_ I figured out it wasn't mysql giving the error, but systemctl. Whenever I try to run any systemctl command, I get the error (systemctl status, systemctl list-units, systemctl start mysql.service)

Comment: Maybe you should consider [filing a bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=systemd+socket)?  (There're lots of `systemd` issues, but I couldn't find one describing yours by glancing over.)  There's also a helpful mailing list [that already discussed a similar issue](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2011-May/002253.html), maybe this thread (or the list) can help you.